# XCODE not Showing debugger area's Log

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7.3

I am using XCode 7.3 . from last 3 days whenver I run Project with Some small changes Simulator shown Up, but degubber area is not showing any Log so I cant not conclude the behavious as I am showing values of some variable priting them. So I found solution for that is : To Clean and Build Project. But I have to repeat this steps even for one line code. And it takes 15 to 20 mins . which is annoying .

So Is there any other Solution

Comment: Did you mean all the value of the variable is nil?

Comment: well NO ; debugger area does'nt show any log. Not even simple print statement

Comment: how do you log message?

Comment: For Swift : - print("Message")

Comment: @KomalK have you tested in objective C? with NSLog(@"Just Test");

Comment: problem is that Debugger sometimes shows ouput and most of time it doesnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check if the problem is one of those options ?!

[image]